# Событие для скачивания видео?нужно отследить момент когда пользователь нажал на скачивание в плеере

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть ли какое-то событие , которое сингнализирует о том, что пользователь нажал на кнопку "скачать видео"? Видео вставляется на страницу как http://htmlbook.ru/html/video и там появляется кнопка play и скачать

нужно отследить момент когда пользователь нажал на скачивание в плеере

Comment: Есть, onclick называется  в JS

Comment: нет, не подходит. нужно отследить момент когда пользователь нажал на скачивание в плеере

Comment: Добавьте в файл или в БД поле и прибавляйте по клику  значение + id и имя пользователя

Comment: Отследить всмысле if(user click == download) { this code }